# How to add ng-click directive to dom element in java script

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click

I have a Button which is being included in the page via jsp include .

```
<button class="btnGreyInactive" name="btn_createNew" id="createNewBtn" style="display: inline-block;" onmouseover="this.className='btnGreyActive'" onmouseout="this.className='btnGreyInactive'"> <img src="/web/images/add.png" alt="Create New" title="Create New" class="vMiddle padRight5">Create New</button>
```

Now  If i am able to successfully add the ng-click directive to the dom element (which is included from the other jsp page), then i can achieve routing through below code.

```
$scope.createNewBtn = function() {
$localStorage.$reset();
    $location.path("/addCarrier");
});
```

Please let me know how to proceed with this scenario.

Comment: You can't just add it in the HTML?

Comment: Like i said, its been included from another jsp via jsp include tag. And i dont think i can add it there.